# XAMPP MySQL batch file

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am using XAMPP to run Apache, PHP and MySQL on a bunch of remote laptops for our clients.  It is just the XAMPP directory with all the files (thumbdrive version, no registry values are added or modified).  I have an install file that puts an icon on the user's desktop that runs start.bat from the XAMPP directory.  Start.bat basically starts Apache, then MySQL, and then opens a browser to localhost.  Everything works great, except that when the icon is clicked the second time, a second mysqld.exe service starts.  Apache does not start twice if the icon is clicked twice, but MySQL does.  I've tried several Google and Stack Overflow suggestions to check if a service is running and, if so, stop the service from starting again; however, none of those worked.

The batch file that starts MySQL basically has this one command:

```
mysql\bin\mysqld --defaults-file=mysql\bin\my.ini --standalone --console
```

How can I keep mysqld.exe from starting twice?  Also, is it a big deal if it is running twice?  Will that cause any problems when running a query from PHP?

Answer (score 1):

I also posted this on StackOverflow (one of our other devs asked the same question).  Here is the answer I found through trial and error (and prayer!):

Modify mysql_start.bat to have this content:

```
@echo off 
apache\bin\pv mysqld.exe %1 >nul 
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto Process_NotFound 
echo MySQL is running 
goto END 
:Process_NotFound 
echo Process %1 is not running 
mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=mysql\bin\my.ini --standalone --console
goto finish 
:finish
```

This checks if the service is running and starts it if not.